# enable/disable buttons with jquery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage where some data are shown. If there is more data than can be shown at once I have a navigation bar enabling one to navigate to the next pages. There are 4 buttons total; "first page", "previous page", "next page" and "last page". If one is at page 1 the first 2 needs to be disabled, if one is at the last page the last 2 buttons needs to be disabled.

Now I have seen bunch of example's (also here at stackOverflow) as to how to do it, problem is: none of them works!

I have tried (JS):

```
doc.getElmByID("button")
button.setAttribute('disabled', true/'disabled')
// (meaning both true and disabled have been tried with no luck).
```

jQuery:

```
$(button).attr('disabled', true/'disabled')
$(button).prop('disabled', true/'disabled')
$(button).button('disabled')
```

Now several of these does actually do something, they remove the "cursor=pointer" option, but the click event remains.

--EDIT--

HTML code

```
            html += '<div id="naviLeft"><img type="button" id="First" class="grey" src="images/dobbelt-pil-disabled.png" title="First page"> </img>';
            html += '<img type="button" id="Previous" class="grey" src="images/pil-disabled.png" title="Previous page"></img></div>';
            html += '<div id="changeRecords"></div>';
            html += '<div id="naviRight"><img type="button" id="Next" class="grey" src="images/pil-r-disabled.png" title="Next page"> </img>';
            html += '<img type="button" id="Last" class="grey" src="images/dobbelt-pil-r-disabled.png" title="Last page"></img> </div>';
            document.getElementById("navi").innerHTML = html;

            $('#First').click(function(){currentTable.First(), setNavigation()});
            $('#Previous').click(function(){currentTable.Previous(), setNavigation()});
            $('#Next').click(function(){currentTable.Next(), setNavigation()});
            $('#Last').click(function(){currentTable.Last(), setNavigation()});
```

...

```
setNavigation = function()
{
if  (currentTable)
{
// currentTable.total and currentTable.currentPage are placeholders for current Page and total pages.

    var current = currentTable.currentPage;
    var total = currentTable.total;

    var first = $('#First');
    var previous = $('#Previous');
    var next = $('#Next');
    var last = $('#Last');

    if  (current == 1)
    {
        $(first).attr('src', 'images/dobbelt-pil-disabled.png');
        $(first).css('cursor', 'default');

        $(previous).attr('src', 'images/pil-disabled.png');
        $(previous).css('cursor', 'default');
    }

    if  (current > 1)
    {
        $(first).attr('src', 'images/dobbelt-pil.png');
        $(first).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $(first).hover(function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/dobbeltpil-chosen.png');},function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/dobbelt-pil.png');});

        $(previous).attr('src', 'images/pil.png');
        $(previous).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $(previous).hover(function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/pil-chosen.png');},function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/pil.png');});
    }
```

Comment: :any particular error??

Comment: `foo.disabled = true;` whit `foo` being the button. (i.e. `foo = document.getElementById('yourButtonId')`. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wg7t9/)

Comment: if button element then `$("button").prop('disabled', true);` if id then `$("#button").prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: sry. forgot. foo.disabled = true dosn't work either

Comment: button.setAttribute('disabled', true/'disabled')
// (meaning both true and disabled have been tried with no luck).

Comment: Can you also show us your html?

Comment: @Molle Sorry but your HTML code is just messed up and wrong. It seems you're lacking basic understanding both of HTML syntax and Javascript. Just giving you the right code might work for you now, but I'd really look into a few tutorials if I were you.

Comment: And what is messed up about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems wrong to me:

```
<img type="button"
```

this should be:

```
<input type="image"
```

and be sure to wrap it with `doc ready` handler:

```
$(function(){
    $('[type="image"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: A second pair of eyes helped :) I was so focused on the functions that I missed the img type=but. It turned out that the functions was OK after all.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$(button).prop("disabled", true);
$(button).prop("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your button is jquery ui is necessary to update the plugin

```
$("button").button();
...
...
..
..
$("button").attr("disabled","disabled").button("refresh");//disabled
$("button").removeAttr("disabled").button("refresh");//enabled
```

if not remove

```
button ("refresh")
```

Comment: "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh' ".
 But it did take away the cursor=pointer and set it to default, but onclick remains.